# M-theory and many-worlds interpretation

Tags: string-theory, quantum-interpretations

I am getting some confusion on whether M-theory accepts many-worlds interpretation. Can anyone show me the reasons or rebuttals for the possibility of the many-worlds interpretation in M-theory? Thanks.

Comment: @Dilaton See [one use of the many-worlds interpretation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=3634652#3634652). I'd say it's pretty useful when you want to get a feel of things.

Comment: @Manishearth Yeah I`ve seen the discussion between You and @DavidZaslavsky, but I dont see how the calculations using the classical Maxwell equations can strenghten the case for the MWI and how a proper inclusion of QED should finally differ from the summation over both (or integration over all) paths. I may be wrong of course ... :-)

Comment: @Dilaton Yeah, I mean that as a standalone theory it may be pretty useless, but since it doesn't have any serious flaws, we can use it to get a feel of things in conjunction with the main theory. Which makes it useful I suppose.

Comment: @Manyshearth Even though I think the MWI is not needed for doing correct calculations in QM, it is probably ok if it helps people getting a feeling for things.

Comment: @Dilaton: While it's not any different    quantum mechanics,     consistientt histories      is still usefu,l, e.g. in scattering amlitudes.

Answer (score 4):

This contains no new information but since nobody else seems to jump in I thought I could transform my comment into a short answer.

Many-worlds is just an (I don't know how useful ...) interpretation of QM and is not (directly) related to M-theory or to the large number of vacua it has as solutions. These are two separate issues or concepts which are sometimes confusingly both called [multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse). So M-theory neither refutes nor accepts the many-worlds interpretation.

Comment: Sorry for bumping up the question on the active question list but I assume there is no way to "quietly" add an answer ...?

Comment: Nope. When mooching around the review section the inability to make ninja edits bugs me, since I can't make more than four edits in good conscience (it clutters up the main page)

Comment: @Manyshearth I the edits are good and worth it, maybe You dont need to have a too bad concience ;-)

Comment: well, good new posts on the main page get pushed down and neglected. So even if the edits are worth it, the impact on newer questions is pretty bad.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand slightly on an existing answer: many worlds depends entirely on how you interpret quantum mechanics, and the interpretational issues have nothing to do with M-theory.  However, M-theory is a quantum theory, so you have to embrace quantum mechanics/ quantum field theory and think about the interpretational issues if you want to understand reality.